# read & overwrite a variable value from a Lua 5.2 file with C#

Tags: c#, lua

I have Lua scripts, that uses variables such as:

```
VERSION_LOCALE = "1.0"
MAX_MONSTERS = 5
FORBIDDEN_MONSTERS = {2827}
```

I would like to make the variables externally configurable using a simple C# Program.

1. Load the Lua script from a dialog
2. Overwrite the file with the modified variables (textbox)
3. The actual variables retrieved from our Lua script, in our example `MAX_MONSTERS` should be returned in the textbox.

[image: Program Idea]

What is the appropriate way to achieve? Here is what I have tried without success:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27219221/18756404

Comment: Can you share specifically what went wrong with the solution you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Read the file contents using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()`
2. Split the lines in to an array using `String.Split()`
3. Parse the value using `String.SubString()` and show the value in the text box
4. Read the value from the text box and update the array
5. Regenerate the new string using `String.Join()`
6. Write the new string to the file using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct @Shameel,
I used the code here to read the information:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(luaPath);


        foreach (var line in lines)
        {

            if (line.Contains("MAX_MONSTERS"))
            {
                Utilis.LogInfo("VARIABLE NAME: " + line.Split('=')[0].Trim());
                Utilis.LogInfo("VARIABLE VALUE: " + line.Split('=')[1].Trim());
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
                TxtMaxMonsters.Text = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
                TxtMaxMonsters.Enabled = true;

            }
         
            if (line.Contains("MIN_MONSTERS"))
            {
                Utilis.LogInfo("VARIABLE NAME: " + line.Split('=')[0].Trim());
                Utilis.LogInfo("VARIABLE VALUE: " + line.Split('=')[1].Trim());
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
                TxtMinMonsters.Text = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
                TxtMinMonsters.Enabled = true;

            }
         }
```

And I used the code below to save the modifications:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(luaPath);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = lines[i];

            if (line.Contains("MAX_MONSTERS"))
            {
                lines[i] = line.Replace(line.Split('=')[1].Trim(), TxtMaxMonsters.Text);
            }
            if (line.Contains("MIN_MONSTERS"))
            {
                lines[i] = line.Replace(line.Split('=')[1].Trim(), TxtMinMonsters.Text);
            }
            if (line.Contains("ITEMS_TO_DEPOSIT = {"))
            {
                lines[i] = line.Replace(line.Split('{')[1].Split('}')[0].Trim(), TxtItemsToDepositID.Text);
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(luaPath, lines);
```